# Android Plot for String Parameters

Tags: string, androidplot

[image]My app requires the Y-axis to have strings like 'Charging', 'Discharging' and 'Charging Failed'. Is it possible to plot a graph with this and have the parameter in question depicted in accordance with these strings on Android Plot?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "depicted".  Is there an actual image that represents each state?  Without knowing more, this sounds like a perfect use case for using the step chart style.

Comment: Hi @Nick, the states are read from a csv file and are as shown in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure I'm understanding the desired visualization but here are the basic steps I would suggest:

To start, you're going to need to convert your CSV data in to XYSeries data.  To accomplish this, you'll need to map your current X/Y string values to numbers.  I'd suggest creating a method that looks something like this:

```
// parses a CSV string into an XYSeries
// for example, DISCHARGE = 1, MPPT = 2
public XYSeries convertCSVToXYSeries(String csvContent) {...}
```

Next, setup your Plot etc. pretty much the same way you would for any other XYPlot as shown in the [Androidplot Quickstart Tutorial](http://androidplot.com/docs/quickstart/).

When you add the XYSeries you get back from convertCSVToXYSeries to your plot, use an XYStepFormatter:

```
StepFormatter stepFormatter  = new StepFormatter(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE);
stepFormatter.setVertexPaint(null); // don't draw individual points
plot.addSeries(series, stepFormatter);
```

Finally, add a custom range value formatter to print your status strings instead of the int values they've been mapped to:

```
        // create a custom getFormatter to draw our state names as range tick labels:
        plot.setRangeValueFormat(new Format() {
            @Override
            public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
                Number num = (Number) obj;
                switch(num.intValue()) {
                    case 1:
                        toAppendTo.append("DISCHARGE");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        toAppendTo.append("MPPT");
                        break;                       
                    default:
                        toAppendTo.append("Unknown");
                        break;
                }
                return toAppendTo;
            }

            @Override
            public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
                return null;
            }
        });
```